# node.js apidoc how to configure index.html for doc page?

Tags: node.js, api-doc

Im new at node,

implementing documentation module,
I have some test file on `/lib` with documentation comments from example.

I run

> ./node_modules/apidoc/bin/apidoc -i lib / -o docs/apidoc

it responds >`info:Done`

now my basic question, how to access this documentation?

http://localhost:8080/doc/index.html

as suggested [here](http://www.slideshare.net/rottmann/api-doc-22669932) doesnt work, I have not configured this path on my main js file,

so how to access the index for the documentation?, where to configure this?, cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The doc is not served at any port. You can access it just by opening doc/index.html file in your browser (from the filesystem itself ex.: file:///home/kyrisu/dev/so/doc/index.html).

Comment: How can I serve it on a port?